# Error finding the python modules/libraries from the /home/ubuntu location

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu

I have been trying on setup PIL module on my Ubuntu System and it has been giving a lots of error. Finally , i am getting issue as:
when i try to run python from /home/ubuntu, it gives me error as:

```
ubuntu@ip-<server>:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:07:12)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "PIL/Image.py", line 90, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name _imaging
```

but if I run the code from /usr/local, it does not return any error:

```
ubuntu@ip-<server>:~$ cd /usr/local/
ubuntu@ip-<server>:/usr/local$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:07:12)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>>
```

there might be an issue with the path or the permission of the required libraries. But i am not sure how to fix this.
I am executing my script from Jenkins and it throws error over there. Please guide how to fix.

Comment: How did you install PIL?

Comment: @pavelsaman  sudo pip install Pillow